# ngShow inside a directive

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a directive with an ngShow statement that depends on some attribute/condition I want to pass. When I hardcode the ng-show it works fine but if I try to assign the value to scope then add to template it does not respond to my form. The rendered html is my source exactly the same though.

```
// Works
app.directive('message', function($filter, moment) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div ng-show="forms.resetForm.$pristine && forms.resetForm.$submitted && forms.resetForm.$invalid" ng-transclude></div>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

    }
  };
});


// No workie
app.directive('message', function($filter, moment) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div ng-show="{{ show }}" ng-transclude></div>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      scope.show = 'forms.resetForm.$pristine && forms.resetForm.$submitted && forms.resetForm.$invalid';
    }
  };
});
```

How can I assign a dynamic ngShow statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to understand how directive attributes work. ng-show expects a boolean expression, evaluated on the scope. So, if you want to put this complex boolean expression in the JS code rather than in the template directly, it should be:

```
template: '<div ng-show="shouldShow()" ng-transclude></div>'
...
scope.shouldShow() = function() {
    return scope.forms.resetForm.$pristine && 
           scope.forms.resetForm.$submitted && 
           scope.forms.resetForm.$invalid;
}
```

Comment: I do understand it wants a boolean and the function is not necessary. See my answer.

Comment: what's the point of using a compile function to dynamically add an attribute on the HTML containing only static text? This is a contrived way of simply putting the static text directly in the template.

Comment: My example is just a simplified version. I create the ngShow text based on the directive attributes. But I may end up using your version - there are pros and cons to each method.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - use ngShow

```
app.directive('message', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="" ng-transclude></div>',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      compile: function(element, attrs) {
        attrs.ngShow =  'forms.resetForm.$pristine && forms.resetForm.$submitted && forms.resetForm.$invalid';
      }
    };
  });
```